# Visit postorder of a binary tree in order to change the content of its nodes

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Given a binary tree, I should visit starting from the leaves, in order to replace the value of each node with the sum of the values ​​of its two child nodes. How should I proceed using a postorder visit?

The structure of each node is shown below.

```
struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *left;   // <- pointer to the left sub-tree
    struct node *right;  // <- pointer to the right sub-tree
};
```

Comment: Is this to replace each node's value with the sum of the values of that node's descendants?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Yes, the aim is to replace each node's value with the sum of the values of that node's children: `parent_value = left_child_value + right_child_value`.

Comment: Calculate the value of the left child's tree (recursive call). Calculate the value of the right child's tree (recursive call).  Add the two together and replace the value with the sum.  It's up to you whether the recursive function returns the value after assigning it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
void postorder_visit(struct node* root) {
  int leftVal = 0;
  int rightVal = 0;

  if(root == NULL)
    return;

  postorder_visit(root->left);
  postorder_visit(root->right);

  //Don't want to change the leaves' values.
  if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
    return;

  if(root->right != NULL)
    rightVal = root->right->value;
  if(root->left != NULL)
    leftVal = root->left->value;

  root->value = leftVal + rightVal;

}
```

Comment: @enzom83 quick question: are the leaves' values pre-initialized?

Comment: That's a remarkably good question.  I guess you have assume that if a node is a leaf node, the value field is initialized.  There isn't much option otherwise — you'd probably get zeros everywhere otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The value at each node will be the sum of the values of its lChild and rChild.

**EDIT**
Edited to handle all integers (Have to do include `limits.h` to use `INT_MAX`)

```
int postOrder(struct node* node)
{
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        return INT_MAX;
    }
    int x = postOrder(node->left);
    int y = postOrder(node->right);
    if(x != INT_MAX)
    {
        node->data = x;
    }
    if(y != INT_MAX)
    {
        node->data +=y;
    }
    return(node->data);
}


//Test code
void printinorder(struct node* node)
{
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }   
    printinorder(node->left);
    printf("%d\t",node->value);
    printinorder(node->right);
}

int main()
{
    struct node* root = newNode(10);
    insert(root,5);
    insert(root,-2);
    insert(root,6);
    insert(root,15);
    insert(root,12);
    insert(root,16);
    printinorder(root);
    printf("\n");
    postOrder(root);
    printinorder(root);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you didn't just do: `node->value = x + y;` ? Also note that a BST is not the same as a Binary Tree (which is what the OP called it). In other words, there's no guarantee implied that the nodes are in any particular order, they could mean something completely different.

Comment: `node->value = x + y;` will make all the values as `0`. The base case returns `0` which will then get propagated all the way to the root. And yes you are right. I misread this as BST. Will edit my answer

Comment: Because you left out handling leaf nodes different from any other type of node. There is also, in your answer, implied that the values are positive. The OP doesn't mention that. However, if non-leaf nodes have a `value` of 0, you can just do: `node->value += (x+y);`

Comment: Yes, I assumed +ve values. But that is easily fixable. In the base case I can return a `sentinal value` and I can do my addition if the value != sentinal value. This way it will work for all integers including 0.